# Grid of numbers with some blue 1s - fill in the missing row

Tags: pattern

I don't know what type of puzzle this is. What is the answer?

[image: puzzle in image form]

> Question 3. (3) Discover the pattern, and write down the missing row of numbers (without spaces). Hint: the blue squares [bold in the transcription] are as important as they look!

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | **1** | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | **1** | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | **1** |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 |

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please could you [edit] your question to include the source of this puzzle (it looks like a picture from a website)?

Comment: Try coloring the cells by number, and the pattern might reveal itself.

Comment: Hi 

My friend shared this with me, it was from an logical deduction practice test he was taking. I could ask him more about the source and reply here. May I ask why the question was downvoted? So severe lol

Comment: Please do ask your friend for proper attribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row is

> 4 3 3 2 3 4 5 5

Because

> Every cell shows the distance from that cell to the nearest blue square.